# Wordpress 3.0 Mult-User - Data Sharing Between Sites

Tags: wordpress, feed, custom-post-type, multi-user

I'm creating a custom solution on Wordpress 3.0, that has multiple different sites using the multi-user capability.

I want to know if Wordpress has any functions that allow you to pull data from the same custom post type across all of the sites.

An example is news. All of my sites have a custom post type called News. I want to be able to feed from all across the sites when pulling in the news somewhere. Does Wordpress have this functionality build in, or can the data only be pulled per site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way might be to use RSS - [WordPress › SimplePie Plugin for WordPress « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simplepie-plugin-for-wordpress/) or [Developer's Guide - Google AJAX Feed API - Google Code](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxfeeds/documentation/) or [Magpie RSS - PHP RSS Parser](http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/) - with a custom post type URL like this:

```
 http://example.com/feed/?post_type=yourposttype
```

from http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-post-types?replies=8